# What is the Precise Definition of a “Complex Vector Space”?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I am studying linear algebra (as a second year) on my own using Axler’s, “Linear Algebra Done Right.”

I have run into a definitional problem that I can’t get past.

Specifically, Axler (and Wolfram, and others) define a “complex vector space” as a vector space in which the field is the complex numbers.  According to this definition, the complex numbers over the real numbers are not a complex vector space, but the complex numbers over the complex numbers are a complex vector space.  This despite the fact that the two vector spaces are identical (or at least isomorphic).

I already see that many theorems concerning eigenvalues/vectors, adjoints, and spectral theory vary according to whether we are looking at complex or real vector spaces.  Thus, the definition of “complex vector space” is critical.

I’m sure there is an easy explanation, but I don’t see it.  Thanks.

Comment: "Axler (and Wolfram, and others) define a “complex vector space” as a vector space in which the field is the complex numbers." That's the definition - what's the question? You'd like an easy explanation of what?

Comment: I'm not sure what your precise question is, but you should look closely at the axiomatic definition of a vector space over a field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition

Comment: You should think about the phrase "$k$-vector space" as telling you which scalars you are allowed to use. A real vector space lets you scale your vectors by real numbers, while a complex vector space lets you scale vectors by complex numbers.

Comment: '...  *over the real numbers*' means that we only take the real numbers as scalars, so for example $i\cdot v$ is *not defined* at all for any vector $v$, as opposed to the case when we deal it as a complex vector space.

Comment: "This despite the fact that the two vector spaces are identical (or at least isomorphic)." - this is not true; the two vector spaces don't even have the same dimension. Over the real scalars, you need two elements of $\mathbb C$ (e.g. $1$ and $i$) to form a basis. Over the complex scalars, you only need one.

Comment: The vector spaces "$\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb C$" and "$\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb R$" have the same *underlying set*, and addition operation, but that does not mean they are the same vector space. It's also nonsense to say they are isomorphic, since the isomorphism must be a linear map, and to define linear maps you need to domain and codomain to be vector spaces with the same field of scalars.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope this gives some insight:

**$\Bbb R$ as an $\Bbb R$-vector space**

This is the real line you are used to. It has a basis consisting of one element, which we can choose to be $1$. You can view this as a vector with just one coefficient. Notice that any $r \in \Bbb R$ can be expressed in this basis as $r \cdot 1$. A vector is just a real number, and we have scalar multiplication that is just the usual multiplication.

**$\Bbb C$ as an $\Bbb R$-vector space**

This is the complex plane. We need two basis elements, for example $1$ and $i$. Now any vector in $\Bbb C$ can be expressed as $a + bi$ with $a,b \in \Bbb R$. If $r \in \Bbb R$ we have scalar multiplication $r(a + bi) = ra + rbi$.

**$\Bbb C$ as an $\Bbb C$-vector space**

Now we're back to being one dimensional. We only need one basis element, $1$ for example. Any element $a + bi \in \Bbb C$ can be expressed as $(a + bi) \cdot 1$. Compare this to the first example and convince yourself that these are essentially the same. Scalar multiplication happens with elements from $\Bbb C$.

Note that, for example, $\Bbb R$ as a $\Bbb C$-vector space does not make sense. We need to be able to multiply by scalars in a meaningful way. For general $z \in \Bbb C$, the product with a real number $r \in \Bbb R$ is a complex number $r \cdot z \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: That helps a lot.  I think any non-mathematician would see the last two spaces as identical.  Do you know whether there are any differences between the last two spaces in applied areas?

Answer (score 4):

It might help to remember that a vector space is defined by more than just the set of vectors $V$. Although we frequently abbreviate it that way, a vector space really consists of four things, $(k, V, {}+{}, {}\cdot{})$: the base field $k$, the set of vectors $V$, the vector addition operation $+$, and the scalar multiplication ${}\cdot{}$. Keeping that in mind will make it easier to understand how $\mathbb C$ can sometimes be a complex vector space and sometimes not.

When we're thinking about $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$, we mean the vector space $(\mathbb C, \mathbb C, {}+{},{}\cdot{})$, where the addition is addition of complex numbers and scalar multiplication is multiplication of complex numbers.

When we're thinking about $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb R$, we mean the vector space $(\mathbb R, \mathbb C, {}+{},{}\cdot{})$,  where the addition is addition of complex numbers and scalar multiplication is multiplication of reals by complex numbers.

So these really are two different vector spaces, even though the set of vectors is the same in both. And one of them is a complex vector space, while the other is a real vector space.

Comment: Are you saying that in a vector space “addition” and “multiplication” are defined as in any ring? I.e. Just the names of two binary operations which could vary from one vector space to another?

Comment: @MPitts Exactly. For example, we could define a real vector space ($k=\mathbb R$) where the set of vectors is $V=\mathbb R_{>0}$, the positive reals; vector "addition" is defined by $v+w:=vw$ (the latter being the _product_ of the two real numbers); and scalar multiplication is defined by $c\cdot v=v^c$. You can show that this obeys all of the vector space axioms (and in fact it is isomorphic to the standard $1$-dimensional $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over itself).

Comment: Great.  That would seem to open up a whole new frontier of questions, problems, and theorems. (Strange though that this wider definition gets little mention.)

Answer (score 1):

In case the other answers are too abstract, here is a concrete example.

Treating $\mathbb C$ as a complex vector space of one dimension,
an example of a scalar is $a = 2 + i.$ An example of a vector is 
$\mathbf v = (1 + 2i).$
We can perform a scalar multiplication of a vector like so:

$$ a \mathbf v = (2 + i)(1 + 2i) = (5i), $$

where $(5i)$ is also a vector in this space.

Now if we take $\mathbb R^2$ as a two-dimensional vector space,
we could make the obvious correspondence between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb C$
such that $(1, 2)^T \in \mathbb R^2$ corresponds to $1 + 2i = \mathbb C.$
But $2+i$ is not a scalar in this vector space.
Instead we would have to treat $2 + i$ as another vector.

It is impossible to treat $(2 + i)(1 + 2i)$ as scalar multiplication in 
$\mathbb R^2$ taken as a two-dimensional vector space,
although in $\mathbb C$ as a one-dimensional vector space this *is* scalar multiplication.
So although $\mathbb R^2$ has *some* properties isomorphic with the corresponding properties of $\mathbb C,$ it's missing at least this one.