# Given something is a complex vector space does this means it is automatically over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I was looking a question mapping from  $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ where $\mathbb{C}$ is a complex vector space and asking to give a function which is linear with respect to addition but was not a linear transformation? I wasn’t sure whether the scalars over the field were automatically real numbers given it is a vector space and I thought the complex numbers over $\mathbb{C}$ was not a vector space. I’ve gotten myself very confused and seem to have forgotten everything I thought I knew!

Comment: It depends on what your definition of complex vector space is. Assuming you take the definition of a vector space to be over _some_ field, you don't necessarily need the field to be the reals. You can, for example, have a complex vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, [as explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3291403/695196).

Comment: Ahh ok, I misunderstood that whole idea- thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathbb{V}$ is a vector space over some field $\mathbb{F}$ with addition + and scalar multiplication $\cdot$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is some subfield of $\mathbb{F}$ then $\mathbb{V}$ would be vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with the same operations.

In your case $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and yes, $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with the standard complex addition and multiplication. So $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard complex addition and multiplication.